# Html UI not outputting correctly in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm kind of new to using coding so I may be missing the obvious here. I'm looking to create something like the output here in this discussion: [How can I add multiple inputs from an HTML UI to a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325826/how-can-i-add-multiple-inputs-from-an-html-ui-to-a-google-spreadsheet). I used the same code format, but somehow the form is blank when I execute the code? Here is the code as modified:

```
    addItem.gs
    function openInputDialog() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
           .showModalDialog(html, 'Make Booking');
    }



  function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(["  ", form.name, form.room, form.guesthouse, form.checkin, form.checkout, form.department]);
  return true;
}
```

The HTML form:

```
Index.html    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <br>
  <form>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    Room:<br>
    <input type="text" name="room">
    <br>
    GuestHouse:<br>
    <input type="text" name="guesthouse">
    <br>
    In:<br>
    <input type="date" name="checkin">
    <br>
    Out:<br>
    <input type="date" name="checkout">
    <br>
    Department:<br>
    <input type="text" name="department">
    <br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
</html>
```

When I run the function, the form only has the dialog "Make Booking", the rest of the form is blank. I've scoured the net for what I could be doing wrong, unsuccessfully of course.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no body tag in your HTML file.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="department"` doesn't have a closing tag

Comment: @Ritz I made a mistake copying the code, the original has the closing tag.

Comment: @Cooper, sorry to ask such a noob question, where would the body tag be put?

Comment: If I add the closing tag, it works for me...can you share the spreadsheet

Comment: <html><head><title>Title if there is one</title><script>var='this where most JavaScript would probably go.';</script></head><body>This where most of your cont goes</body></html>

Answer (score 0):

I used most of your code and this should work for you.
Code.gs:

```
function addMyData(form) 
{
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sh.appendRow([form.name,form.room,form.guesthouse,form.checkin,form.checkout,form.department]);
}

function showMyDialog()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlhelp');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Title');
}
```

htmlhelp.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="name">
    <br>
    Room:<br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="room">
    <br>
    GuestHouse:<br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="guesthouse">
    <br>
    In:<br>
    <input type="date" name="checkin">
    <br>
    Out:<br>
    <input type="date" name="checkout">
    <br>
    Department:<br>
    <input type="text" value="" name="department">
    <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.addMyData(this.form);google.script.host.close();" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: google.script.host.close() will not work deployed as a webapp.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! Now I just need to figure out how to ensure the data added goes to a specific range!