# How can I edit a google sheets HTML UI element after submitting form?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets

From [How can I add multiple inputs from an HTML UI to a Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325826/how-can-i-add-multiple-inputs-from-an-html-ui-to-a-google-spreadsheet) I have copied the following script from the top answer, and made **2 additions** which I've marked with comments in the scripts below.

**addItem.gs**

*Addition #2 has been made to the file below*

```
function openInputDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Add Item');
}

function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //Addition #2
  document.getElementById("status_value").innerHTML = "Submitted!"; 
  sheet.appendRow(["  ", form.category, form.item, form.manupub, form.details, form.quantity]);
  return true;
}
```

**Index.html**

*Addition #1 has been made to the file below*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <br>
  <form>
    Category:<br>
    <input type="text" name="category">
    <br>
    Item:<br>
    <input type="text" name="item">
    <br>
    Manufacturer or Publisher:<br>
    <input type="text" name="manupub">
    <br>
    Details:<br>
    <input type="text" name="details">
    <br>
    Quantity:<br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity">
    <br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
    <!-- Addition #1 -->
    <p>Status: </p><p id="status_value"></p>
</html>
```

**Problem:**

The script above fails when it gets to Addition #2. It seems it cannot find the id=*status_value* element in the html.

**Note:**

I want the html to be updated from the .gs script file because, I have use cases where the script may take a while, I want to change the status message as the script gets to certain milestones in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ".gs" files run serverside and the html runs clientside. You can not pass data back and forth as if they are running together, hence the 'google.script.run' [functionality](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

If you want to send data back from the serverside script after a function is called from the client side using that functionality, just `return` it.

You can then use the returned data to make a change clientside:

Html

`<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run .withSuccessHandler(function (data) {
document.getElementById("status_value").innerHTML = data;
google.script.host.close() ;
} ) .itemAdd()" />`

.gs

```
function itemAdd(form) { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.appendRow([" ", form.category, form.item, form.manupub, form.details, form.quantity]); 
return "Submitted" ;
 }
```

Comment: I actually wrote this from my phone (bored on a long road trip) so there may be some errors but the gist is there!

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks interesting, and I may be able to achieve something similar to what I am trying to do. How would I access the "Submitted" value in the HTML? If I have one example, I can modify for my purposes.

Comment: The '. onSuccessHandler()' takes a function with a parameter. When you return a value from the server used you can just access that parameter see the 'data' parameter in my example above.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Very helpful to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that

> ... browser-based features like DOM manipulation or the Window API are not available.

The above means that getElementById can't be used on server-side code (.gs).

---

From my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432676/1595451) to [Google Apps Script Javascript Standard Support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37768501/1595451)

> From
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features
>   (January 27, 2019)
>
> > **Basic JavaScript features**
> >
> > Apps Script is based on [JavaScript
> >     1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6), plus a few features from [1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7)
> >     and 1.8.
> >     Many basic JavaScript features are thus available in addition to the
> >     built-in and advanced
> >     Google services: you can use common objects like `Array`,
> >     `Date`,
> >     `RegExp`,
> >     and
> >     so forth, as well as the `Math`
> >     and `Object`
> >     global objects. However, because Apps Script code runs on Google's
> >     servers (not client-side, except for HTML-service
> >     pages), browser-based features like DOM manipulation or the `Window`
> >     API are not available.